# Hibernate ManyToMany Multiple Entries

Tags: java, hibernate, equality

I am using Hibernate 4.3.
I have created below entity for `Student`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
public class Student {

    public Student(){
    }

    public Student(String name, Set<Course> courses){
        this.studentName = name;
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="STUDENT_ID")
    private long studentid;
    @Column(name="STUDENT_NAME")
    private String studentName;
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="STUDENT_COURSE",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="COURSE_ID")
    )
    private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>(0);

    //Getter Setter Methods
}
```

And another entity is `Course`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSE")
public class Course {

    public Course(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "COURSE_ID")
    private long courseID;
    @Column(name = "COURSE_NAME")
    private String courseName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="courses")
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>(0);

    //Getter Setter Methods

    // I have added equality and hashcode check below

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Course)) {
            return false;
        }
        Course anotherCourse = (Course) obj;
        // return this.courseName == anotherCourse.courseName;
        return (this.courseName == null)? anotherCourse.courseName == null : this.courseName.equals(anotherCourse.courseName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return courseName.hashCode();
    }
}
```

In my application I have code as:

```
// Configuration and Session creation for Hibernate

Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();
courses.add(new Course("Maths"));
Student st1 = new Student("ABCD", courses);
session.save(st1);

courses.add(new Course("Physics"));
Student st2 = new Student("EFGH", courses);
session.save(st2);
```

In the above case it inserts invalid data, as both courses for both the students.
Which is incorrect, but as in Java the object is same so that is correct.
But I want the courses to map as defined above. How to handle this at Hibernate end ?

I tried another option as:

```
Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();
Set<Course> courses1 = new HashSet<Course>();
courses.add(new Course("Maths"));   
Student st1 = new Student("ABCD", courses);

session.save(st1);

courses1.add(new Course("Maths"));
courses1.add(new Course("Physics"));
Student st2 = new Student("EFGH", courses1);
session.save(st2);
```

But this time it created two different courses for same `courseName = "Maths"`.
Even if I have created a `equals` and `hashCode` method implementation.

Need solution, how to handle this in Hibernate.

Comment: I have modified the line `return this.courseName == anotherCourse.courseName;` to `return (this.courseName == null)? anotherCourse.courseName == null : this.courseName.equals(anotherCourse.courseName);`. But still it is not working, it is inserting two records for `Maths` in Course table.

Comment: if you need it to work, first save all courses, then assign them to students and save students.

Comment: No need to save all `Course` first. Just it was required to have same object for both `"Maths"` course. My mistake was, I was doing `new Course("Maths")` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for the issue as below:

```
Course maths = new Course("Maths");
Course physics = new Course("Physics");

Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();
Set<Course> courses1 = new HashSet<Course>();

courses.add(maths);
Student st1 = new Student("ABCD", courses);
session.save(st1);

courses1.add(maths);
courses1.add(physics);
Student st2 = new Student("EFGH", courses1);
session.save(st2);
```

In this I have created objects for `Course` and used the same object in both set. So in the database it is created only one row entry for course `Maths`.

Thus solved the purpose.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue comes from the implementation of your `equals()` method in the `Course` class

Indeed, when you do this :

```
return this.courseName == anotherCourse.courseName;
```

, you compare the memory reference of `this.courseName` with the `courseName` of `anotherCourse`.

Instead, you should use the equals() method, like this :

```
return this.courseName.equals(anotherCourse.courseName);
```

, which compares the string content instead of the reference.

In your second attempt, since you create 2 objects (with the same value), and since your implementation of `equals()` in `Course` compares the reference (the memory address) of the objects instead of their content, Hibernate believes those are different.

Comment: I have added comment in question regarding the same.

Comment: Your solution is a very bad idea. You are working around your problem by reusing the same object, but you are not solving it. If you keep it that way, you will inevitably have bugs in the future. How would you do if you have to retrieve it from the database and then attach ?? Your equals implementation is just wrong, don't adapt your biz-code due to invalid trivial method implementations !

Comment: My mistake, it seems that I read your "second option" code instead of the solution code :) Indeed now you are good ! 
Please note that fixing the equals() was very important for the future - You can now compare two Course objects representing the same Course, even if the 2 objects are not the same in memory, which will inevitably happen once your app gets more complex :) 
Basically you are now comparing a `unique business key` (assuming course names are unique), which is the `Best Practice`.